# is there a way to group radio button for php usage?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, radio-group

I'm wondering if let's say I have 4 radio buttons named red blue yellow and green but if none of them are unchecked and a person submits the form, let's say will echo no radio checked.
if I use the if statement I can only think of using something like

```
if(empty($_GET(["red"])) || empty($_GET(["blue"])) || empty($_GET(["green"])) ||empty($_GET(["yellow"])))
{
echo "blah";
}
```

But that's really long for that if statement if there's two more radio I want to add or something let's say I have a name field an ya....that's gonna be a long long if statement...

is there a way to group them together and make them shorter?

Comment: `if(count(array_intersect_key(array("red"=>1,"blue"=>1,"green"=>1,"yellow"=>1),$_GET))>0)`. Not that short though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Radio buttons are grouped by default if you give them the same name

```
<input type="radio" name="group" value="1"> Option 1  
<input type="radio" name="group" value="2"> Option 2
```

The selected option will then be passed to php in `$_POST['group']`

Comment: oh ya omg...you are right...ah! I have been trying other php and stuck for three days...>.<" suddenly this I got messed up omg! thanks stupid question I had.

Comment: No worries, I think everyone has done that at least once. Feel free to accept it as the answer :)

Comment: I've done it so many times these days haha...oops though already accept hehe I pressed the up instead oops...alright accepted ^_^